# Adding CSS to webpack build

Tags: css, webpack

I have a fairly simple webpack project - built using the Webpack guide. See https://github.com/timburgess/webpack-postcss-tailwind

There is a `style.css` in the `src` directory but there is no .css being added to the `/dist` directory on build.

Reading further, any css should be added as an inline style and that's not occuring.

Resolved with https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin per Richards answer.

Comment: Now that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack will bundle the css files referenced via `import` statements in your source javascript files into the output javascript file (bundle.js). You'll see the classes being applied to the webapp at runtime via inline `<style>` tags applied dynamically to the html.

Many developers do not think this behaviour appropriate and will use a special plugin to get webpack to produce seperate bundled `.css` files that you then reference in your html using the traditional (and caching friendly) `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bundle.css">` tag. See:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin